# Is pairing an i5 6200U with 16 GB of RAM a bad idea?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, intel-core-i5

Every site (except for one) I look on, the allowable/offered combinations of processor (i5 or i7) and RAM (8 or 16 GB) are as follows:

1. i5-6XXXU 8 GB
2. i7-6XXXU 8 GB
3. i7-6XXXU 16 GB

What I want is an i5-6XXXU with 16 GB of RAM.

- I went to HP's site to customize a Spectre. I chose i5-6200U and 16 GB and I got an error message: "Selected Processor and Graphics is only available to 8 GB memory option."
- Tried using the laptop filters on Dell's site. Once I chose Intel i5 as the processor filter, I couldn't choose "12 GB & up" as a RAM option anymore.
- etc etc

The first laptop I'm having success with is the Lenovo T460, but because no other site lets me combine i5 and 16 GB, I'm concerned that maybe Lenovo's site isn't checking to make sure the parts I'm choosing are compatible.

Is there actually a reason why the i5-6200U with 16 GB of RAM is not offered (except Lenovo)? Why? If not, then why wouldn't anyone offer it? Is it all about the money?

Comment: You're merely looking at the available standard options.  Since the only model you mentioned is the Lenovo T460, I went to check its specs and it surely supports the i5 and up to 32GB of RAM.

Comment: For the 13" HP Spectre x360 it was also the i5-6200U. When I went to customize it, it only allowed me to select 8GB. Would you mind taking a look at that one as well?

Comment: The HP Spectre is made to be so thin that it doesn't allow memory expansion, which is why they are limited to the standard options they defined for it.  Since it can not be upgraded, stocking costs force them to limit the number of options.

Comment: Ah thank you! If you write that as an answer, I can accept it. I don't have enough points on here to upvote a comment. All my points are stackoverflow hah

Comment: @JuliePelletier Oops, but the thinness of the Spectre doesn't explain why the i7 option allows 16GB of RAM? Maybe it's just that i5/16GB isn't as popular? Hmm..

Comment: I called HP to ask them, but they gave the same answer about thinness. When I asked why I could choose the i7 + 16GB but not the i5, they didn't have an answer. Ended up buying the T460 for the i5 16GB option.

Comment: It's all marketing!